# jQuery.data() namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I avoid conflicts with other jQuery plugins using `$.data()`?

I was thinking I could use a single key to store my data like

`$(el).data('myplugin', { foo: 'a', xyz: 34});`

and access it like `$(el).data('myplugin').foo` etc.

But how can easily change a value, without overriding the whole data? Like changing the value of "foo".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not using

```
$(el).data('myplugin.foo')
```

and

```
$(el).data('myplugin.xyz')
```

?

So if you don't need to access more than one value at the same time, you avoid useless indirections and tests.

Comment: The *.key* needs to be outside the ()s

Comment: @m90: He's suggesting to literally name the key `"myplugin.foo"`.

Comment: @Rocket never even thought of having a *var.iable*. Do you know if this would be valid syntax?

Comment: @m90 You just can't use it directly. It has to be referenced using array notation such as what is in dystroy's answer or `$(el).data()['myplugin.foo']`. `$(el).data().myplugin.foo` would throw an error due to `myplugin` not being defined on the data object.

Comment: thanks! do you know how can I remove only my data when calling $.removeData() ?

Comment: You can't remove all your data with this method, only one after the other (by passing the name e.g. 'myplugin.foo'). If you have to do so, then, he, that's the argument for other answers like the one of Kevin B. It depends on what your plugin does. One answer doesn't fit them all :)

Comment: @dystroy calling `removeData()` on an element with no arguments will remove all data associated to that element (including data that you may not have defined yourself). http://api.jquery.com/removeData/

Comment: Yes but I guess the question is about removing all items related to "myplugin" without impacting other plugins. With your solution, it's easy (calling jQuery.removeData(e1, "myPlugin"). And it's harder with mine as you have to know all used names. Don't disagree with me as I'm finally saying your solution is better than mine !

Comment: @dystroy: I wasn't trying to say one was better than the other, I'm just correcting a statement that could be taken the wrong way. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 7):

Just change the property you want to change.

http://jsfiddle.net/rQQdf/

```
var el = $("<div />");    
el.data("myPlugin",{ foo: "foo" });
console.log(el.data("myPlugin").foo); // foo
el.data("myPlugin").foo = "bar";
console.log(el.data("myPlugin").foo); // bar
```

As far as namespace conflicts, one solution is to generate a timestamp at runtime (when the plugin is defined) and use that timestamp in your namespace. It still isn't 100% protected against conflicts in the fastest browsers, but it gets pretty close.

Comment: this works because the object is a reference, I should have though it earlier :(

I was avoiding this approach just because I thought I would need to do,
`var data = el.data("myPlugin"); data.foo = "bar"; el.data("myPlugin",data);`

+1 Kevin.

Answer (score 3):

I personally use a hyphen-separated naming convention which prefixes class names, IDs, data properties, etc with an abbreviated identifier of the entity which owns the code, and one for the area of functionality.

If I were working on a chart program for company Foo, my prefix might be:

```
foo-chart-
```

This allows me to make all company identifiers unique to the company, and areas of code unique to each other (so as to avoid colliding with other devs in other areas of functionality).

**Contrived example:**

```
<button id="foo-chart-refresh" class="foo-chart-interact" data-foo-chart-last="201205031421">Refresh Chart</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lastRefresh = $('#foo-chart-refresh').data('fooChartLast'); // see docs on .data() for case/hyphenation handling
</script>
```

I find using a hyphen fits well with almost any place my identifiers would be needed--either as a markup attr value *or* name, or in code, etc. You could use any char which fits your needs (`.` is very common)

Comment: Me three.  It's particularly apparent in the bootstrap javascript modules `data-slide` `data-slide-to`. Namespacing also appears in the events but with periods `slid.bs.carousel`.